# How to exclude certain files while creating war file using jar command?

Tags: java, linux, jar, war

I am using command `jar cvf MyWarFile.war <list all files and dir to be part of war file with space in between>` to create a war file in linux. I don't want to specify each and every file/dir in the command rather I just want to use * (to create war file out of files in current dir)  . What should I do to exclude certain file/dir while trying add all the files (using *) in the directory to the war file that i am creating.

I am looking for something like

```
jar cvf MyWarFile.war * <how to exclude certain file/dir>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard `!` and parenthesis to create your `war` file. Anything written inside parenthesis will be excluded

```
jar cvf MyWarFile.war !(file1)
```

If you want to exclude multiple files from `jar` file/folder selection you can use `|`.

```
jar cvf MyWarFile.war !(file1|folder1)
```

Comment: Thanks @fahad-siddiqui .

Comment: this only seems to work in Java 11, not Java 8. When limited to that, one can use the find command on Linux to limit the input that jar gets like:

jar -cvf MyWarFile.war $(find . -not -path "*/.git/*" -not -name .git -not -name .gitignore -not -name Dockerfile -not -name .)